# Common user authentication widget

Tags: authentication, authorization

I need to make a common form to enter user name and password and include this page for all sites (as an iframe) as login option. This common form will validate the username and password, and return validity. Based on that parent site can allow user for authentication.

I need non-cloud based solution. Main objective is not entering user name password for many sites (hence site admins can’t log user name password and password all sites not required to access password repository). SSO is also not required.

Comment: Sounds like you need the browser to post a username, and password (with https) to the parent site, and on successful authentication, write a cookie token to the browser, for that session. That is my understanding on how authentication normally works. I think this is normally handled by some web framework. I'm not to sure how to do it with javascript.

Comment: My primary requirement is to avoid active directory credentials are entered to all connected sites. Credentials are entered only to a one site and it gives the user status.